# Android M Content Provider Permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have seen similar questions, but I think I'm running into Android M specific trouble.

I have two Android applications.  One extends ContentProvider to manage a SQLiteDatabase.  The other presents a GUI and reads/writes data from/to the Content Provider.  The two applications work together successfully until I try to set permissions on the Content Provider.

I receive the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
>   provider com.example.productkit.ProductKit from ProcessRecord{ce096cd
>   27369:com.example.myapplication/u0a60} (pid=27369, uid=10060) requires
>   com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER or
>   com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER

The AndroidManifest.xml file for the Content Provider looks like this:

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.productkit">

    <permission android:name="com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER"/>    

    <application>
        <provider
            android:name=".ProductKit"
            android:authorities="com.example.productkit"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

The AndroidManifest.xml file for the GUI application looks like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

My understanding is that the application needs to request permission(s) at run time with Android M.  As an experiment, I've tried to do that with the following test code:

```
    int hasPermission = checkSelfPermission("com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER");
    if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {"com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER"},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    hasPermission = checkSelfPermission("com.example.productkit.permission.CONTENT_PROVIDER");
```

Unfortunately hasPermission does not equal PERMISSION_GRANTED following the call to requestPermissions().

If I use the same code to gain access to a built-in permission, like to the CAMERA, a dialog appears and I can grant permission to the application.  That behavior does not happen for my Content Provider's permission.

Comment: "My understanding is that the application needs to request permission(s) at run time with Android M" -- only `dangerous` ones. Where is this `<permission>` defined? I do not see in your manifest extracts.

Comment: I named the permission in the <provider> section of the manifest.  Does it also need a separate definition in the manifest?

Comment: I updated the question with my attempt at defining the <permission>.  The protection level should be "normal" by default.

Comment: I think this will be helpful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html  Declare your new permission with `<permission ... >` inside your manifest.

Comment: Note that with this configuration, you must install the provider app before the client app. Otherwise, when the client app is installed, Android will not know about the custom permission, and your client app will not get it. Try uninstalling both apps completely, then install the provider, then install the client, then see if they work properly. Or, duplicate the `<permission>` element in both manifests.

Comment: I think that might have been the problem.  I've been trying things and reinstalling the apps all day.... just now I uninstalled both of them and installed them in the order you described.  It worked!

Comment: Isn't there a way for the permission to be granted no matter in which order you install the apps? It's a huge mistake on Android's side, for they cannot foretell in which order users are going to install the apps.

Comment: I finally managed to do it using a not very "clean" workaround. Both the provider and the client applications declare the permission as `<permission>` in their manifests. This way, the OS learns about the existence of the permission by either one application or the other and it doesn't matter which is installed first. Not neat, since only the provider app should declare its permission, but it prevents this Android shortcoming.